# Error in Spotify. Something went wrong, please try again or check out our help area

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am currently developing an application in python and at the moment of authentication it sends me error.

```
import sys
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

scope = 'user-library-read'

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "Usage: %s username" % (sys.argv[0],)
    sys.exit()

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print track['name'] + ' - ' + track['artists'][0]['name']
else:
    print "Can't get token for", username
```

[image: Spotify error]

Comment: Usually you get a plain html page with an error message if it's your fault the authorization didn't work. I'd recommend trying again, it's probably just accounts.spotify.com 500-ing.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the `callback URL` - make sure that it is set up in your application on the Spotify developer portal.

You need to have a valid URL there for Auth to work. Make sure you have a trailing `/` if your app uses that. Make sure http/https is set correctly depending on your environment setup.

For more info, you can follow this: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/